# Windows skipping language-specific resources

Tags: winapi, resources, localization, internationalization

I'm playing around with the Windows API, and I'm trying to use multilingual resources to load language-specific menus and stuff. However, for some reason, Windows absolutely refuses to load Bosnian (Latin) resources if there are US English alternatives. Loading resources via [`FindResourceEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) works. I'm on XP SP3 and Bosnian (Latin) is set in my regional settings.

**main.c**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PTSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    TCHAR string[64];

    /* Message box properly outputs "This is German (DE)." here. */
    SetThreadLocale(MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(LANG_GERMAN, SUBLANG_GERMAN), SORT_DEFAULT));
    LoadString(hInstance, TEST_STRING, string, sizeof(string)/sizeof(string[0]));
    MessageBox(NULL, string, TEXT("Message"), MB_OK);

    /* Message box outputs "This is English (US)." - WTF?! */
    SetThreadLocale(MAKELCID(MAKELANGID(LANG_BOSNIAN, SUBLANG_BOSNIAN_BOSNIA_HERZEGOVINA_LATIN), SORT_DEFAULT));
    LoadString(hInstance, TEST_STRING, string, sizeof(string)/sizeof(string[0]));
    MessageBox(NULL, string, TEXT("Message"), MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

**resources.rc**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
STRINGTABLE
{
    TEST_STRING                   "This is English (US)."
}

LANGUAGE LANG_GERMAN, SUBLANG_GERMAN
STRINGTABLE
{
    TEST_STRING                   "This is German (DE)."
}

LANGUAGE LANG_BOSNIAN, SUBLANG_BOSNIAN_BOSNIA_HERZEGOVINA_LATIN
STRINGTABLE
{
    TEST_STRING                   "This is Bosnian (Latin)."
}

LANGUAGE LANG_FRENCH, SUBLANG_FRENCH
STRINGTABLE
{
    TEST_STRING                   "This is French (FR)."
}
```

**resource.h**

```
#define TEST_STRING                             40000
```

Comment: are you sure u wanna use plain c?

Comment: It's sufficient to illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The language selection mechanism in LoadString (and in general all resource retrieving APIs) was broken starting with Vista (because of the MUI mechanism addition at system level).

The best current practice is to store each language in a separate resource only dll and you access the resources using the DLL's hInstance. And you can and either load the dll yourself, or use the newer MUI API to do that (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd319076%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Huh. Well, anyway, I ran that code on XP, so I'm still confused.